# Facebook request through inbox? reference in FBML Docs

Tags: api, facebook, messaging

The FBML docs refer to a way to send requests through Inbox:

"Note: You can also send requests and invites through Inbox."

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/req-choice

However, all other evidence suggests there is no formal way to do this.  Is that correct and is the statement above just inaccurate?

Answer (score 0):

As of June 6, 2012 even if it was possible the FBML functionality would be removed. Refer to the [Requests Dialog Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) as to how achieve this from now on.